# Using preg_match to validate a string format

Tags: php, regex

I have an html form with an input for a sales order number which should have the format of K1234/5678. It should always start with the letter K then 4 numbers, a / and followed by another set of 4 numbers.

I'm trying to validate the formatting using preg_match and I'm getting lost in the syntax of preg_match.  From http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php I've gotten close. With the following code I'm able to verify that it contains at least 1 letter, some numbers and at least 1 non- alphanumeric value.

```
$so= $_POST['so'];
if (preg_match(""/^(?=.*[a-z]{1})(?=.*[0-9]{4})(?=.*[^a-z0-9]{1})/i", $so))
{
    print $so;
}
```

What is the correct syntax to use for this? Is preg_match even the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("#^K[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}$#i", $so)
```

Explanation:

The `#` characters are regular expression delimiters - they indicate the start/end of the pattern. The `^` and `$` indicate the start and end of the string - this means that it will only match if your sales order number is the only thing in the string. The letter `K` means match that letter, `[0-9]{4}` means match a digit exactly 4 times. The `i` at the end means a case-insensitive match - the `K` will match either "K" or "k".

When developing regular expressions, I often use regular expression testers - these allow you to enter your data and try a bunch of different things to refine your regex. Google [PHP regex tester](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+regex+tester&oq=php+regex+tester) to find a list of tools. Also, there's a **very** complete reference to regular expressions at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.  I will look into a regex tester, seems like they could be pretty helpful.